# Layout of custom tag handlers within a package

Tags: java, jsp, java-ee-6, custom-tags

I have a custom tag handler test/StubCTag.java that is a simpletag. There is a testing.tld file that defines the ctag:-

```
<?xml ... ?>
<taglib ...>
...
<tag>
<name>stubctag</name>
<tag-class>test.StubCTag</tag-class>
</tag>
</taglib>
```

When packaging this as a jar archive the files are layd out as follows:-

```
testing.jar
-----------
/META-INF/testing.tld
/META-INF/classes/test/StubCTag.class
```

When using the custom tag in a jsp page with prefix *testprefix*, browser shows a 'Unable to load tag handler class "test.StubCTag" for tag "testprefix:stubctag". I have double checked the archive and the tld and class files are present. I searched online but it didnt get me anything which mentions anything about placement of tag handlers as part of a library.

Could someone tell me how to package class files as a customtag library?

Comment: Could you post the URI in your tld and how you declare it in your jsp?

Comment: URI = http://testexample.com & in jsp it is using taglib with urn set to URI.

Comment: The uri is [http://testexample.com](http://testexample.com), clarifying my previous comment here.

Comment: <%@ taglib uri="[http://testexample.com](http://testexample.com)" prefix="testprefix" %> is how im using the tags in jsp.<br/>The jar file location is in the war file of the web app in which I have included testing.jar at /WEB-INF/lib.<br/>I recompiled the code with same java versions. Repackaged the library and web app. Redeployed the war. Same error.<br/>I packaged a dummy .tag file in the jar, that works fine on the same jsp. Error shows up only for testprefix:stubctag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jar in question contains tag handler classes and tags.
I changed the file layout to

```
/META-INF/testing.tld
/test/StubCTag.class
```

rest remains same. No more errors, jsp page shows output as intended so problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Could you to include your taglib this way:

```
<%@ taglib uri="uri element in tld" prefix="testprefix" %>
```

Comment: I typed like this <%@ taglib uri="http://testexample.com" prefix="testprefix" %> in the jsp page. Same error.

Comment: You have an extra **;** in your declaration after the **"testexample.com"**

Comment: <%@ taglib uri="[http://testexample.com](http://testexample.com)" prefix="testprefix" %> this is what I wrote, im just getting familiar with commenting so kindly bear with my mistypes

Comment: and you jar is in your webapp WEB-INF/lib folder ?

Comment: What application server are you using, and which Java / jstl / jsp versions ?

Comment: SE 1.6, ee 6, tomcat7, jsp 2.2

Comment: Other pages serve properly and tags as well so I believe the problem is something else. Thanks for your comments.